# Exporting Mysql to .txt - how to format the text?

Tags: php

I'm exporting some mysql data to a text file. The data can be selected by checkboxes from a table.

I want to format the text that will be in text file. How do I do that?

This is my code:

```
 <?php
if ($_POST['exporttxt']) {
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
   $export_id = $checkbox[$i];
$text = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM tickets WHERE id='$export_id'");
$text = mysql_fetch_assoc($text);
$text = $text["code"];
$filename = "export";
$filedate = date("Y-m-d");
$fileext = ".txt";
$fileall = $filename.$filedate.$fileext;
ob_end_clean();
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"$fileall\"");
   header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output).";\n");



echo($text);


}
}

exit();

?>
```

The data that will be exported are numbers containing of 16 digits. After every number I want to have a line-break. Also if possible I would like to have a space after 4 digits for every number, example:

Number non-formatted:  1234567891234567
Number formatted: 1234 5678 9123 4567

How can I do that?

Comment: *sigh* Capitalise your "I"s and sentences end in periods, not commas!

Comment: Hey, thanks for your useful input, unfortunately not everyones native language is english.

Comment: so `$text['code']` = a 16 digit number ?

Comment: Seems like a valid question, why -1?

Comment: What have you tried so far? From what you have shown, you reassign the same variable name to various things and then echo it to screen, you decide to put the length of a zero-length string into the "Content-Length" header field and that's about it. No attempt to create a file, no attempt to actually echo more than one thing on screen, no attempt to protect against SQL inject attacks etc. I suggest you buy a book on learning PHP and MySQL and go from there

Comment: yes, `$text['code']` is one or multiple 16 digit numbers - i don't want to create a file, the selected content is offered to download as a text file.

Comment: You must have seen by now that "I" is capitalised, given that you can speak the language. So it just means that you couldn't be bothered to format your post :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [chunk_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)

```
echo chunk_split($text, 4, " "); <-- you seems forgotten a line break
```

Off-topic issue :-

1. where is `$output` defined ?
2. you don't have `ob_start()`
3. repeatedly use $text for various data type( mysql result resource, array, string)

Comment: this works as expected, although how do i add a line break ? Sorry i'm a complete tool with php.

Answer (score 2):

You need to represent the number as a string:

```
$num = preg_replace("/(?<=\d)(?=(\d{4})+(?!\d))/", " ", $num);
```

Turns `"1234567891234567"` into `"1234 5678 9123 4567"`

A new line would be represented by `\n`

Comment: Ah, you are right with number_format! Sorry, I was in a hurry! +1 for the fabulous PCRE approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ->

```
// divide in to chunks of 4 characters
$chunks = str_split($text['code'], 4);
//Convert array to string.  Each element separated by the given separator.
$result = implode(' ', $chunks);
```

Working example : http://codepad.org/4Zf1ABKX